# Router NAT block uploads from subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, iptables, amazon-vpc, trafficshaping

I have this scenario.

[image: Scenario]

I need to block large uploads from the private network (10.0.30.0) to the internet. I am routing 0.0.0.0/0 traffic from the private network via the Bastion / Router eth1.

There I am forwarding: sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

And as we are behind a NAT: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

It works.

Then I am trying to limit just the download bandwidth from the eth1 (so limiting the upload from the subnet) but I am not being able to mark correctly the packages:

```
#! /bin/bash
NETCARDOUT=eth0
NETCARDIN=eth1
MAXBANDWIDTH=1000000
SUBNET=10.0.30.0/24
mark=1
bandwidth=100

#Allow forwarding using one interface only
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $NETCARDOUT -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -i $NETCARDIN -j MARK --set-mark $mark

# reinit
tc qdisc del dev $NETCARDIN root handle 1
tc qdisc add dev $NETCARDIN root handle 1: htb default 9999

# create the default class
tc class add dev $NETCARDIN parent 1:0 classid 1:9999 htb rate $(( $MAXBANDWIDTH ))kbit ceil $(( $MAXBANDWIDTH ))kbit burst 5k prio 9999

# traffic shaping rule
tc class add dev $NETCARDIN parent 1:0 classid 1:$mark htb rate $(( $bandwidth ))kbit ceil $(( $bandwidth ))kbit burst 5k prio $mark

# filter that bind the two
tc filter add dev $NETCARDIN parent 1:0 protocol ip prio $mark handle $mark fw flowid 1:$mark

echo "Subnet $SUBNET is attached to mark $mark and limited to $bandwidth kbps"
```

It seems that the iptables rule with the mark is not working.

So far I have managed to block eth0 upload, but it is not the same. For that I use a TC-only script without marking connections or packages. I don't want the Bastion upload to be restricted so it is not a valid solution.

Next step would be to reduce de bandwith for connections with lots of bytes. I think connbytes is the way to go but I need to first resolve this step. I think the MASQUERADE is what is making my life hardder :D

Thank you!